# Facebook: [FBSession activeSession] crashes app

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using the **Facebook iOS SDK 3.0**, and I just upgraded to the new Facebook iPhone app (5.0).
Now, whenever I call `[FBSession activeSession]`, my app crashes with the error:

> -[SBJsonParser errorTrace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x499700

This only happens if I have the new Facebook 5.0 app installed. If I deinstall it, and wait for a little bit, my app runs fine. Also, this never happened before with the older version of the Facebook app.

Has anyone run into this before? There seems to be a bug report with the same issue on the Facebook Developer page, but it hasn't been dealt with yet.

Comment: I'd love to accept your answer to this question :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer to this question. But to encourage users in Stackoverflow to answer you must accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Ok sure, I wasn't aware of that. Will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of conflict within the SBJson libraries. We're working to get this resolved and should be fix ready .

Comment: I'm surprised that a major bug like this hasn't been fixed yet. My app crashes every time I try to login and I thought it was my fault. I guess I'll have to go back to the 2.x SDK. *sigh*

Comment: Hi, the 3.1.1 update of the SDK addresses SBJSON linking errors. Please give it a try: https://github.com/downloads/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/FacebookSDK-3.1.1.pkg

Hope this helps